# Find the number

Tags: c#, algorithm, c#-2.0

**This is a problem statement.**

Consider a number 2345. If you multiply its digits then you get the number 120. Now if you again multiply digits of 120 then you will get number 0 which is a one digit number. If I add digits of 2345 then I will get 14. If I add digits of 14 then I will get 5 which is a one digit number.

Thus any number can be converted into two one digit numbers in some number of steps. You can see 2345 is converted to 0 by using multiplication of digits in 2 steps and it is converted to 5 by using addition of digits in 2 steps. Now consider any number N. Let us say that it can be converted by multiplying digits to a one digit number d1 in n1 steps and by adding digits to one digit number d2 in n2 steps.

Your task is to find smallest number greater than N and less than 1000000000 which can be converted by multiplying its digits to d1 in less than or equal to n1 steps and by adding its digits to d2 in less than or equal to n2 steps.

How to solve it in C#...

Comment: Switch to a 64 bit system.

Comment: Having 1 billion strings in memory will surely result in being out of memory. Maybe you should only add the strings that match your criteria?

Comment: You are creating an array of 1000000000 strings. Of course you run out of memory.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Arrays are limited to 2GB consecutive bytes, and references will be taking 4 bytes (or 8 on a 64 bit build?)  Either way, even a 64-bit system can't have an array with that many references.

Comment: you've been asking this problem a couple of times already. this is the exact problem that you have only that this time, you need to count the steps.

Comment: @MatthewWatson that changes in .NET 4.5; see `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>` - however, I am not for one moment saying that it is a *good idea* to have a huge array here

Comment: @MarcGravell Indeed that is true! But this question is tagged as C# 2 :)

Comment: does the user input n1, n2 (number of steps?)

Comment: @aiapatag the variable here is `N`

Comment: @MarcGravell It's possible that n1 and n2 are also variable - it isn't very clear.

Comment: @Dukeling yeah it's true, even the d1 and d2 can be a user variable. *Your task is to find smallest number greater than N and less than 1000000000 which can be converted by multiplying its digits to **d1** in less than or equal to **n1 steps** and by adding its digits to **d2** in less than or equal to **n2 steps**.*

Comment: @aiapatag no, `d1` and `d2` are not user variables; they are **defined** in the problem statement as the result of the "multiply digits repeatedly" / "sum digits repeatedly" step. Likewise, `n1` and `n2` are not user variables; they are **defined** in the problem statement as the number of steps required for each of those operations. This is the line: "Now consider any number N. Let us say that it can be converted by multiplying digits to a one digit number d1 in n1 steps and by adding digits to one digit number d2 in n2 steps."

Comment: that made sense. :D I stand corrected :) thanks @MarcGravell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're simply approaching / interpreting the problem incorrectly; here's a stab in the dark:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // check our math first!

        // You can see 2345 is converted to 0 by using multiplication of digits in 2 steps
        int value, steps;
        value = MultiplyToOneDigit(2345, out steps);
        Debug.Assert(value == 0);
        Debug.Assert(steps == 2);

        // and it is converted to 5 by using addition of digits in 2 steps
        value = SumToOneDigit(2345, out steps);
        Debug.Assert(value == 5);
        Debug.Assert(steps == 2);

        // this bit is any random number
        var rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int N = rand.Next(0, MAX);
            int result = Execute(N);
            Console.WriteLine("For N={0}, our answer is {1}", N, result);
        }
    }
    const int MAX = 1000000000;
    //Now consider any number N.
    static int Execute(int N)
    {
        // Let us say that it can be converted by multiplying digits to a one digit number d1 in n1
        // steps and by adding digits to one digit number d2 in n2 steps.
        int n1, n2;
        int d1 = MultiplyToOneDigit(N, out n1),
            d2 = SumToOneDigit(N, out n2);

        // Your task is to find smallest number greater than N and less than 1000000000 
        for (int i = N + 1; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            int value, steps;

            // which can be converted by multiplying its digits to d1 in less than or equal to n1 steps
            value = MultiplyToOneDigit(i, out steps);
            if (value != d1 || steps > n1) continue; // no good

            // and by adding its digits to d2 in less than or equal to n2 steps.
            value = SumToOneDigit(i, out steps);
            if(value != d2 || steps > n2) continue; // no good

            return i;
        }
        return -1; // no answer
    }
    static int MultiplyToOneDigit(int value, out int steps)
    {
        steps = 0;
        while (value > 10)
        {
            value = MultiplyDigits(value);
            steps++;
        }
        return value;
    }
    static int SumToOneDigit(int value, out int steps)
    {
        steps = 0;
        while (value > 10)
        {
            value = SumDigits(value);
            steps++;
        }
        return value;
    }
    static int MultiplyDigits(int value)
    {
        int acc = 1;
        while (value > 0)
        {
            acc *= value % 10;
            value /= 10;
        }
        return acc;
    }
    static int SumDigits(int value)
    {
        int total = 0;
        while (value > 0)
        {
            total += value % 10;
            value /= 10;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two memory problems I can see; the first is the generation of lots of strings - you might want to approach that something like:

```
static int SumDigits(int value)
{
    int total = 0;
    while (value > 0)
    {
        total += value % 10;
        value /= 10;
    }
    return total;
}
```

(which is **completely untested**)

The second problem is the huge list; you don't need to store (in `lstString`) every value just to find a minimum. Just keep track of the best you've done so far. Or if you **need** the data for every value, then: don't store them as a `string`. Indeed, the `i` can be implied *anyway* (from the position in the list/array), so all you would really need would be an `int[]` of the `cnt` values for every value. And `int[1000000000]` is 4GB just by itself, so would require the large-array support in recent .NET versions ([`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). But much better would be: just don't store it.

Comment: `byte[]` may be a better idea than `int[]` (255 should be sufficient), although this still may not be the right way of approaching the problem.

Comment: @Dukeling indeed, it is a very wrong way of approaching it; the only "right" way is to start again from scratch, with a better understanding of what the algorithm wants to do (which I did in a separate answer)

Answer (score 2):

> But it's throwing  `System.OutOfMemoryException` .

That simply mean you're running out of memory. Your limit is `1,000,000,000` or roughly 1G. Times 4 bytes for a string reference that's already too large for a 32 bit system. Even without the actual strings.

You can store your answers more compactly in an `int[]` array but that would still show the same problem.

So, lower your limit or compile and run on a 64 bit PC.

Answer (score 0):

A for effort :)

Now doing together. You can of course do refactoring.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _17082903_smallest_greatest_number
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int N = 2344;
            int n1 = 0;
            int n2 = 0;

            int d1 = SumDigits(N, ref n1);
            int d2 = ProductDigits(N, ref n2);

            bool sumFound = false, productFound = false;

            for (int i = N + 1; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                if (!sumFound)
                {
                    int stepsForSum = 0;
                    var res = SumDigits(i, ref stepsForSum);

                    if (res == d1 && stepsForSum <= n1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("the smallest number for sum is: " + i);
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("sum result is {0} in {1} steps only", res, stepsForSum));
                        sumFound = true;
                    }
                    stepsForSum = 0;
                }

                if (!productFound)
                {
                    int stepsForProduct = 0;
                    var res2 = ProductDigits(i, ref stepsForProduct);

                    if (res2 == d2 && stepsForProduct <= n2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("the smallest number for product is: " + i);
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("product result is {0} in {1} steps only", res2, stepsForProduct));
                        productFound = true;
                    }
                    stepsForProduct = 0;
                }

                if (productFound && sumFound)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        static int SumDigits(int value, ref int numOfSteps)
        {
            int total = 0;
            while (value > 0)
            {
                total += value % 10;
                value /= 10;
            }

            numOfSteps++;

            if (total < 10)
            {
                return total;
            }
            else
            {
                return SumDigits(total, ref numOfSteps);
            }
        }

        static int ProductDigits(int value, ref int numOfSteps)
        {
            int total = 1;
            while (value > 0)
            {
                total *= value % 10;
                value /= 10;
            }
            numOfSteps++;
            if (total < 10)
            {
                return total;
            }
            else
            {
                return ProductDigits(total, ref numOfSteps);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: reading the question, you need to consider the two things *together*; not in isolation

Comment: trying to do them together.

Comment: It is not clear what the purpose of the `smallestStepsSum` etc is here; the terms `d1`, `d2`, `n1` and `n2` are all well-defined in the problem statement - they are not user variables. They are computed precisely from any given value of `N`.

Comment: reediting but i see that this has already been answered but anyways.